# "no such column" on select from join

Tags: sql

I have two tables with `firstname`, `lastname` and `amount`.

I can do a left join:

```
select * from spi left join dp 
on spi.amount = dp.amount
and lower(spi.firstname) = lower(dp.firstname)
and lower(spi.lastname) = lower(dp.lastname);
```

which gives good results:

```
|#   |firstname     |lastname    |amount|dp.firstname |dp.lastname  |dp.amount
|----+--------------+------------+------+-------------+-------------+---------
|1   |saumeh synah  |s*****      |50.0  |             |             |
|2   |Neda          |M*****      |1000.0|             |             |
|3   |Mansoor       |B********** |100.0 |             |             |
|4   |Hanna         |W****       |50.0  |Hanna        |W****        |50.0
|5   |Kristen       |A****       |40.0  |Kristen      |A****        |40.0
|6   |David         |B******     |10.0  |David        |B******      |10.0
```

Now I want to select just the rows that are missing from `dp`.

So I write:

```
select * from ( 
select * from spi left join dp 
on spi.amount = dp.amount
and lower(spi.firstname) = lower(dp.firstname)
and lower(spi.lastname) = lower(dp.lastname) )
where dp.amount = null;
```

but I get the error

```
no such column: dp.amount
```

Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the derived table. Just try a simple query:

```
select spi.* 
from spi left join dp 
on spi.amount = dp.amount
and lower(spi.firstname) = lower(dp.firstname)
and lower(spi.lastname) = lower(dp.lastname) 
where dp.amount IS null ;
```

Answer (score 2):

dp.amount does not exist as you've created a derived table in your `select * from (select * from...)`

That inner set of parenthesis creates a derived table so your reference to dp doesn't exist outside those parens. Bring your `where dp.amount = null` inside the last parenthesis and push your semi-colon to the outside.

```
select * from ( 
select * from spi left join dp 
on spi.amount = dp.amount
and lower(spi.firstname) = lower(dp.firstname)
and lower(spi.lastname) = lower(dp.lastname) 
-- this will never find results as NULL will never equal anything
-- where dp.amount = null
where dp.amount IS NULL) AS D;
```

Comment: `where dp.amount = null` will result in 0 rows. Always.

Comment: @ypercube Excellent catch, I was focused on the syntactical snafu and didn't event think about the broken logic ;) Updating response now

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to use a `sub query` where dp does not exist.

```
select * from spi left join dp 
on spi.amount = dp.amount
and lower(spi.firstname) = lower(dp.firstname)
and lower(spi.lastname) = lower(dp.lastname)
WHERE dp.amount IS NULL
```

**EDIT:** Here are some [nice examples about JOIN](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm 100% understanding, but would this work?

```
select dp.firstname,dp.lastname,dp.amount
from dp,spi
where dp.firstname=spi.firstname
and dp.lastname=spi.lastname
and dp.amount is null;
```

Comment: This effectively makes it an inner join so it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
   select * from ....
   where dp.amount is null;
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be better name nested select:

```
select * from ( 
select spi.firstname, spi.lastname, spi.amount, dp.firstname f, dp.lastname l, dp.amount a from spi left join dp 
on spi.amount = dp.amount
and lower(spi.firstname) = lower(dp.firstname)
and lower(spi.lastname) = lower(dp.lastname) ) as x
where x.a = null;
```